# Image format compatibility between ROS QImage

Tags: opencv, qml, rgb, ros, qimage

I have "rgb8" format msg delivered via ROS topic subscription.
How may create a QImage out of it and let the qml Image display the picture on it?
Currently I'm working on the following code snippet.

```
QImage *VideoPlayer::Mat2QImage(cv::Mat const& src)
{
    QImage *imgPtr = new QImage((const uchar *) src.data, 
                src.cols, src.rows, src.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
    imgPtr->bits(); 
    return imgPtr;
}

void VideoPlayer::imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
{
  static int count = 0;
  try
  {
    try {
        Mat imgMat = cv_bridge::toCvShare(msg, "rgb8")->image;

        delete imgProvider->currentShot;
        imgProvider->currentShot = Mat2QImage(imgMat);
    ...
}
```

(*currentShot) is fecthed by imageRequest(...) method from qml side's 'source' property.

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to [QQuickImageProvider](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickimageprovider.html). Create q ROSImageProvider class that inherit QQuickImageProvider and implement requestImage() or requestPixmap(), and then register it in QMLEngine:

```
engine->addImageProvider(QLatin1String("ros"), new ROSImageProvider);
```

And then you can using the following QML syntax to get image:

```
Image { source: "ros://some_id" }
```

You can refer to the Qt documentation for full example.

Comment: Thanks but, my qml already calling requestImage() method as needed. The problem is qml Image is not displaying the image transmitted(I guess). So, I think I'm ignorant on image encoding format or something. In qml file I have this section: "Image { ... source : "image://images/" + imageSN ... }"

Comment: 1. Have you tried to save the QImage into file and verify it?
2. Is there any error message in debug message?

Comment: In fact, I just did it. It saves png file correctly. It is done by "imgProvider->currentShot->save("delta.png");" -- this command. Here, currentShot is a pointer to a QImage.

Comment: Then, could a QML Image item show this PNG file correctly?

Comment: Yes, it does. I used the delta.png file as the initial image of the qml Image. It shown perfectly.

Comment: If so, the image encoding/format is correct, there must be something wrong in your requestImage() ...